# Add items to combobox from datagrid in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I currently have a WPF project which retrieves data from a CSV (username and email), so that new users can be easily added, and stores it into a Datagrid.

What I can't seem to work out is how to get the items from the first column into a ComboBox.

Below is the code which loads the CSV data.

```
    //Location of CSV File
    string CSVDataBase = @"C:Test\Users.csv";

    //Create Collection for DataGrid Source
    ICollection CreateDataSource()
    {
        //Create new DataTables and Rows
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;

        //Create Column Headers
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("User", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Email", typeof(string)));

        //For each line in the File
        foreach (string Line in File.ReadLines(CSVDataBase))
        {
            //Split lines at delimiter ';''

            //Create new Row
            dr = dt.NewRow();

            //User=
            dr[0] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(0);

            //Email =
            dr[1] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(1);

            //Add the row we created
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        //Return Dataview 
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        return dv;
    }
```

This is the XAML for the DataGrid.

```
    <DataGrid Name="DG1" IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Visible" Height="100" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want the `ComboBox` inside your `DataGrid` or as a separate control?

Comment: As a separate control, however I have found a way to load directly from CSV into the ComboBox now using streamreader, which means I no longer need a datagrid at all :)